# Heroku: how to install python dependency within app folder

Tags: python, heroku

Can anyone please shed some light on how to "install" a python library directly on the app folder and be able to use it with the .py file? I have to tweak a library for my specific use and installing through requirements.txt is not an option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are many approaches, so this is probably too broad and / or too opinion-based to be on-topic. One option is to submit your changes to the upstream project. This is probably best if you can swing it since you don't take on additional maintenance burden and using it is straightforward. Another is to fork the library, modify it, publish it back to PyPI or Conda Forge or a private package index, and depend on it. A third is to [vendorize it](http://bitprophet.org/blog/2012/06/07/on-vendorizing/).

Comment: Chris, more specifically, i need to edit some javascript inside the library, this has been done on the local version in my environment... this library dependends on other libraries... I am not sue how to go about under any of the options you described...

Comment: Editing third-party libraries should generally be a last resort. If you can provide more concrete information in your question, specifying the library and a [mcve] representing the changes you've had to make we might be able to help. Otherwise, as I said in my first comment, this is too broad.

Comment: Chris, the issue is not modifying the library... the library has been modified. and it is working locally. I need to get the local version working on heroku. Modifying was the only option. The issue here is given a modified library, how do i go about it...

Comment: What exactly is stopping you from modifying the library on heroku as well?

Comment: Mister, i thought about that, but from what I read the dynos get updated and any changes are lost. Plus I would loose the changes if i needed to redeploy. However, if you have an alternative let me know!

Comment: Let me rephrase that: *How* are you modifying the library in question? Does your .py script modify the library on startup? Did you manually modify the library?

Comment: I manually edited javascript within the python library... it works fine in my local enviroment.